# Given $X=\left \{ a,b,c,d,e,f \right \}$ prove if the subset collection of $X$ defined as $Y$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology

Given $X=\left \{ a,b,c,d,e,f \right \}$ prove if the subset collection of $X$ defined as $Y=\left \{ X,\varnothing,\left \{ c \right \},\left \{ b,d,e \right \}, \left \{ b,c,d,e \right \} ,\left \{ b \right \} \right \}$ then $Y$ is a topology otherwise prove why not.

well as the title says , I need to profe if $Y$ define a topology, otherwise prove why not,

I have little knowledge of topology and I don't know how to proceed.

so any insight or solution would be of  great help for me,

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of a topology:

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set. A set $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of $X$ is
> said to be a topology on $X$ if
>
> (i) $X$ and the empty set, $\emptyset,$ belong to $\mathcal{T}$
>
> (ii) **the union of any (finite or infinite) number of sets in $T$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$**, and
>
> (iii) the intersection of any two sets in $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$.

Since $\{c\} \cup \{b\}=\{c,b\}$ is not in $Y$, $Y$ is not a topology.